# How to make tumblr "HTTP POST" api requests?

Tags: api, http, post, tumblr

The tumblr api for reblogging [Tumblr Reblog](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#reblogging) is of type HTTP POST and also Tumblr haven't implemented the cross domain policy. All the HTTP GET api calls, i have implemented using "JSONP", but how to proceed with HTTP POST api calls ?

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, you cannot make `POST` requests to tumblr's api from a browser.

- JSONP uses `<script>` tags to make the request, which the browser will only `GET`.
- CORS is not enabled, so you cannot make the `POST` request yourself.

Comment: Hey Thanks for that . But many of the tumblr api's including tumblr Oauth api to get Request Token , are POST requests.. So dynamic creation of "form" element / use of iframes the only way to get away with this?